# CRA & React Leaflet : Module parse failed: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

I am attempting to use React Leaflet with a Create-React-App and I am getting the following error when I try to do:

```
    const center = [51.505, -0.09];

    const polyline = [
        [51.505, -0.09],
        [51.51, -0.1],
        [51.51, -0.12],
    ];

    const redOptions = {color: 'red'}

    return (
        <MapContainer center={center} zoom={10} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
            <TileLayer
                attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            <Polyline pathOptions={redOptions} positions={polyline}/>
        </MapContainer>
    )
```

```
./node_modules/react-leaflet/lib/VideoOverlay.js 10:25
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:25)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   var overlay = new LeafletVideoOverlay(url, bounds, options);
|   if (options.play === true) {
>     overlay.getElement()?.play();
|   }
|   return createElementObject(overlay, extendContext(ctx, {
```

I am using `"react-leaflet": "^4.1.0"`

I've followed the other answers and change my package.json to

```
 "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
```

But the problem persists, has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: What version of `react-scripts` do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Updating to `"react-scripts": "^5.0.1"` fixed this